# Python set sorted, Why so fast?

Tags: python, sorting

Why is Python built-in `sorted` on a set is so fast?

I mean, incredibly fast, I used it with a set of 80000 entries and it takes very very short time (0.0 is the output of the `time.clock()` difference).
Is that some kind of optimization?

Are the records already sorted inside the set?

And, by the way, how is sorted for set implemented? Can you give me the code?

Comment: How are you creating the set and what's in it? It's possible the set is already sorted.

Comment: If the elements of the set were integers, then they would be, since integers will `hash` to themselves.

Comment: @Alp But that doesn't benefit that *algorithmic* complexity of Merge sort (of which Tim sort is based). Also, since the number of buckets < number of elements, I find it unlikely that there is a direct "already sorted" correlation.

Comment: @user2864740: AFAIK there is no maximum length of a run, so Timsort will complete extremely quickly (it will find a single run).

Comment: Timsort specifically differs from merge sort in trying to identify and make use of already-sorted ranges.

Comment: @Alp I'd love to see refinement/verification of such hypothesis in an answer - I'm going with 80k isn't a representative/interesting problem , but it would be interesting to see different wall-clock time vs data comparisons :)

Comment: Python's sorting algorithm is implemented in C, and sorting 80.000 elements really isn't that much of a problem with today's CPUs.

I just tried it with 80.000 random floating point numbers, they sorted in 0.07 seconds on my 5-year-old PC.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that I use a key function, so the already ordered entries can't be a case.

Comment: @Dunadan This honestly doesn't seem like an interesting problem. If you create a *list* of 80k elements (randomized data representing whatever was in the set), does it still have similar wall-clock time (i.e. "instantaneous")? If so, what about 800k? 8M? 80M? Also, do make sure that you really *do* have 80k elements in the set. Until there is *specific* data in which a list/set differs or sorting shows an "abnormal" time (which requires a baseline comparison), it's just "meh".

Comment: I've just tried the same with lists and it looks identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special magic: the sorting is implemented in C, efficiently. `time.clock` is not the ideal way to benchmark Python code, since the resolution of its output can be quite low on some platforms. For best results, use the `timeit` module to measure elapsed time.

There is also no special algorithm to sort sets. The `sorted` built-in, when called on a `set` (or anything else, for that matter) does the equivalent of:

```
def sorted(iterable):
    templist = list(iterable)
    templist.sort()
    return templist
```

So, the real magic is [in the `list.sort` method](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/babb9479b79f/Objects/listobject.c#l2037). (The implementation is explained in some detail [in the adjacent file.](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/babb9479b79f/Objects/listsort.txt))